# GWT JSNI jquery, use ui:field to select element in callback not work

Tags: gwt, jsni

```
public class SettingMailPage {
    @UiField
    ButtonElement save;
    @UiField
    AnchorElement input;


    SettingMailPage()
    {
       bindActions(save.cast(),input.cast());
    }


    private native void bindActions(JavaScriptObject save, JavaScriptObject input)
    /*-{
          $wnd.$(save).click(function () {
            $wnd.alert($wnd.$(input).size());//always 0, why?
          });
    }-*/;
}
```

I'd like to know why the bind action works while in callback it fail to select that element, and any workaround. Thanks

EDIT:

```
   private native void bindActions(JavaScriptObject save, JavaScriptObject input)
    /*-{
          var thatInput=input;
          $wnd.$(save).click(function () {
            $wnd.alert($wnd.$(thatInput).size());
          });
    }-*/;
```

will work, but not know the reason, could someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `bindActions` is evaluated before the click callback, the callback has no chance accessing the `input` in the state it was when passed to the method.

The only way to do so is locking the state by holding a reference (like you smartly did), or wrapping the entire binding in a closure (terribly cumbersome and redundant), which will look like this:

```java
private native void bindActions(JavaScriptObject save, JavaScriptObject input) /*-{

    (function(in) {
        $wnd.$(save).click(function () {
            $wnd.alert($wnd.$(in).size());
        });
    })(input);
}-*/;
```

It's all about context; remember that inside the callback, you're referring to the ***function owner*** (which is save button). See the [ridiculously famous article on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) on the subject.